# creating alexa backend as python webservice without lambda

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I am creating an alexa skill that has a backend which needs to be connected to some inhouse databases. So i am skipping the lambda part. My plan is to create a bottle\flask webservice, which i can expose to the internet.

Is there any quick tutorial available on creating python alexa webservice backend without lambda.

I got this tutorial from which are helpful.
http://www.makermusings.com/2018/01/13/securing-self-hosted-alexa-skills-with-python/

Comment: you should check out [this](https://www.udemy.com/comprehensive-alexa-skill-development-course/) course on Udemy.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most popular 'python webservice without lambda" library I've seen for Alexa.

https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask